# WCF return types

Tags: .net, wcf

What is the list of valid WCF return types? I know some but I want to know all of them:

- Primitive types (string, int32, etc...)
- Complex types with DataContract or Serializable attributes
- Stream
- Message
- SyndicationFeedFormatter

void? POCOs?

Comment: Your first 2 items cover just about everything...

Comment: `void` is totally legitimate if your method contains the `IsOneWay=True` attribute on it - a "fire-and-forget" method with no return values

Comment: `void` is legitimate without IsOneWay as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you stated.
Everything Darin stated.

Plus...

Void is a valid return type.
Wrapped in a (intentionally omitted) SOAP envelope:

```
<VoidResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
```

POCOs with DataContracts and DataMembers are valid just like any other serializable object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically everything that the serializer used in the binding could handle. Also note that since .NET 3.5 SP1 `DataContract` and `DataMemeber` are no longer necessary, WCF will serialize all public properties, but it is a good practice to put them.